# Excel VBA automated Sheet creater

Tags: vba, excel

Im wondering how i could create an Excel VBA that makes new Sheets and takes the names from a column with the range A2:A100 and only creates sheets if these cells arent empty.
My Sheet with the names looks something like this :

```
Variant | Title | Number
V1        Test1   1.1
V2        Test2   2.1
```

This means, that new Sheets with the names V1 & V2 should be created.
Furthermore i would want them, if possible, to have the exact same Content

```
A1 : productnumber A2 : amount
```

EDIT

Used this code now in Order to create the Sheets :

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList() 
 Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range 

 Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A10") 
 Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown)) 

 For Each MyCell In MyRange 
 Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet 
 Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet 
 Next MyCell 
End Sub
```

Changed "Summary" to my Sheets Name and adjusted the Range. As mentioned, i want the file to create Sheets based on the cell contents of A2:A100 only if the cell contains anything at all. Furthermore i am still not able to set the Contents of the new Sheets that are created

Comment: What efforts have you made yourself - any code? There are many resources online.

Comment: OK, that's better. Where do product number and amount come from?

Comment: Productnumber and amount are put in manually (The data is exported as an excel sheet from a 3rd party program called "E-Plan". This data is then used in a Pivot Chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the basic method nailed, just added a check that the cell contains something and used a worksheet variable for the new sheet which is easier to use if you need to do things to it.

I don't know what you mean when you say you are "not able to set the Contents of the new Sheets"?

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:A100")

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'creates a new worksheet
        ws.Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        ws.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Artikelnummer", "Menge pro Schrank", "Anzahl Schränke", "Menge Gesamt")
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I didnt really explain it very well. Sorry for that. I meant that is still need the macro to put "Artikelnummer" in cell A1, "Menge pro Schrank" into cell B1, "Anzahl Schränke" into cell C1 and "Menge Gesamt" into cell D1 on each of those new Sheets. EDIT : If possible the Sheets should be created between my First sheet "Übersicht" and my Second Sheet "Rechner". Thanks for your help even though i explained really bad! :)