# Excel: Make multiple new sheets based on content of a column

Tags: excel

I'm a (former) software dev (including JS and VBA) but not familiar with Excel macros or formulae.

I have a spreadsheet that I want to turn into many spreadsheets based on the contents of a column.

So my *one* sheet:

```
Row Name Etc.
1    Anne a 
2    Anne b
3    Anne c
4    Bob  b
...
1500 Zack e
```

becomes *many* sheets based on column "Name"

```
[Anne]
Row Name Etc.
1   Anne a
2   Anne b
3   Anne c  

[Bob]
Row Name Etc.
1   Bob  d

...

[Zack]
Row Name Etc.
1   Zack e
```

I'm doing my research but I'm new enough that I can't really adapt anything I find that's similar.

Step 2 will be to output each sheet to its own .xlsx file - but I'd rather not to do that in the same step as above because I have some things I have to do to the data first. **(Though I could do step 1 and 2 together if that's easier.)**

There's 60 Names and 1500 records and I do this monthly so any effort-saving steps are worth it.

Thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've removed the scripting tag, since it specifically says: "This tag is non-specific. Use a specific script tag instead." What language have you chosen for this task? What have you found on SO that is similar?

Comment: If not  'scripting' what tag is good? 'Macros'? I assumed macros are, by default, VBA, but I could use something else. I found this VBA, but it's not SO: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/duplicate-sheet-excel-vba/

Comment: VBA likely, or maybe office-scripts. I guess the point is, it'd be helpful to pick a language first and then share relevant research. A helpful query might be: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+new+sheets+based+on+column+value+excel+vba+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: So far, I haven't found anything in SO that's suitable but I'm still looking.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll mess about with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853250/excel-vba-automated-sheet-creater